# Confused about this Regex expression behavior

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The phrase that is causing the issue:

```
## synonym:g
```

The regex expression:

```
^## (intent|synonym|lookup|regex):(\w+\+?\w+?)$
```

Why does this expression not match the phrase above?

But modifying the regex above to this:

```
^## (intent|synonym|lookup|regex):(\w+)$
```

matches the phrase.

Comment: Spell it out: `\w+\+?\w+?` matches one or more word characters, possibly followed by a `+`, followed by one or more word characters. But you only have one word character at the end of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the final portion of your current regex:

```
(\w+\+?\w+?)
```

Contrary to what you might think, this does *not* match the letter `g`.  Instead, it says to match *two* or more letters, with an optional `+` in between them.

Here is what you might be trying to do here:

```
^## (intent|synonym|lookup|regex):(\w+(?:\+\w+)*)$
```

The trailing portion of this regex would match:

```
g
g+g2
```

etc., but it would not admit a trailing `+` which is not followed by one or more word characters.

### Demo

Comment: Almost. I want to be able to exclude the following phrase `## synonym:g+` but include `## synonym:g+g2`. If the plus is there, it should be followed by a word.

Comment: I sort of suspected this, but did not go this far in my original answer.  Check the updated answer now.

Comment: Thanks, that perfect!